# iPad Air 2 Launch to White Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, air

On the iPad Air 2, running iOS 9.3.2 Apple has been mentioning that our iOS app is loading to a white screen on launch. We've physically bought an iPad Air 2 and are running the same OS, but on launch are completely unable to reproduce this white screen. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: The App while being send to apple may have been damaged. Just Resubmit it and everything should be fine.

Comment: Resubmitted a few times @BashirSidani :(

Comment: Hi Sharan,  I am encountering the same issue. You got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an iOS system problem. You can update your iOS to the latest version. If you don't know how to do this, you can finish it via RecoveryTool Fix Recovery.